# Flutter: Navigate between 3 Pages

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to have the following structure for my project:

```
import 'loginForm.dart' as LoginForm;
import 'dashboard.dart' as Dashboard;

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Test',

    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {

      '/': (context) => LoginForm.LoginForm(),

      '/dashboard': (context) => Dashboard.HomeApp(),
    },
  ));
}`
```

now I want to switch between those pages. Like this:

Mainpage -> (automatically) LoginFrom -> (after login) Mainpage -> Dashboard

The way back should be possible too. How can I implement that? I don't want to have all the Widgets in one .dart file. Or is my approach the wrong one? Is there another (maybe better) way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, that should work. On `LoginForm` Widget add a button (for instance) with action like this:

```
onPressed: () {Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/dashboard');},
```

Answer (score 0):

This will take you to login

`onPressed: () { Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');}`

This will take you to Dashboard and also prevent the user from going to log in when he or she clicks on the back button

`onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('', (Route<dynamic> route)=>false);}`